# File upload over multiple pages

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm creating a php form that works in this way:

1) The user fills the form and add a file to upload;

2) The submitted information is shown to the user for confirmation;

3) Upon confirmation, a email is sent with all the data, including the file.

My problem is that I get access to the uploaded file on the second step, but not on the third step. Due to security reasons, it's not possible to resend the file on the second step by creating a input file field with a default value (the uploaded file).

It's possible to achieve what I'm trying to do, without having to copy the uploaded file to another folder?

Comment: Without copying the file somewhere? No.

Comment: Why would you want to send the same file from the client to the server _twice_?  Store it somewhere server-side and just refer to it on each step.

Comment: Can't you save the location in a session, and pick it up on the third step?

Comment: I don't want to send it more than one time. I just needed to know if there is another way, since I don't need to save the uploaded file. But I guess that storing the file and than referencing it will be better. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question was to place the actual file upload only on confirmation page. There was no way to "carry" the file upload from a page to another in the way I wanted to.
Thanks for the replies.